# Formatting TSQL date to mm-dd-yyyy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, formatting

I have a date in Datetime2 format and it is coming up as yyyy-mm-dd. Is there a way to reformat it so it is mm-dd-yyyy?

```
                CASE 
                WHEN CAST(ai.[Due Date] AS DATETIME2)  < GETDATE() THEN '[due]' + LEFT((ai.[Due Date]),10)
                WHEN CAST(ai.[Due Date] AS DATETIME2) IS NULL THEN ' '
                ELSE LEFT((ai.[Due Date]),10)
            END AS [TD]
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest leaving the formatting to the front end. But if you are deadset on formatting it coming out of the database look at convert. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Have to agree with Sean on this one. Converting this to a string in this case means you basically stripped off the time portion. If you didn't want a time portion in the first place you could have used a smaller data type, otherwise return the datatime2 as a date and do the conversion in the UI, where it could then be displayed according to the users culture etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand how date values work in a database. **There is no human-readable format**. When you see `DateTime` or `DateTime2` values formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd` what you're seeing is something shown by your debugger or query tool for convenience; the actual value used in the database is binary, not human readable, and is intended to be efficient for storage, indexing, and date arithmetic.

If you need to see a value in a specific format, you must `convert()` or `format()` it to a type in the `varchar` family as part of the query. Or, even better, **let your application code/reporting tool do this for you**, and just return the original value.

I also see indication these dates are potentially stored originally in a `varchar`, or `nvarchar` column. If so, **it is a *major* flaw in the schema design.** You will get significant performance benefits and save yourself some big headaches down the road if you can start storing these values using a type from the `DateTime` family in the first place.

With this in mind, and because it's not clear what you're starting from, let's look at five scenarios, in order of preference:

#### The column already uses a type from the `DateTime` family, and you can let your application/reporting tool handle the format

Good for you using a real DateTime value in the schema. That's what we expect to see. Even better, suddenly everything gets *really* simple in your SQL and the entire snippet in the question reduces to just this:

```
 ai.[Due Date] AS [TD]
```

#### The column already uses a type from the `DateTime` family, but the client system can't format

This is still pretty good. The schema is still okay, and in this case we can still simplify the original code somewhat:

```
COALESCE(
    CASE WHEN ai.[Due Date] < GETDATE() THEN '[due] ' ELSE '' END 
    + FORMAT(ai.[Due Date], 'MM-dd-yyyy')
, ' ') AS [TD]
```

#### The column uses the a type from `varchar` family, but you can fix it to use `DateTime2`

I say "fix" here, because now the schema really is *broken* as is. But that's okay: you can fix it. *Do that.* Then use the code from a previous scenario.

#### The column uses the a type from `varchar` family and you can't fix it, but at least the raw data always uses a semantic 'yyyy-MM-dd` format

Bummer. You're stuck with a broken schema. But we can at least take advantage of the well-formatted data to make things ***much*** more efficient by using cast/convert on the `get_date()` expression to match the column, rather than vice versa as it is now, like this:

```
WHEN ai.[Due Date] < CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 120)
```

Now we're doing a string comparison instead of a date comparison, which is generally slower and, well, just wrong. But we can get away with it because of the nice format in the data, and the saving grace is we only need to cast the one `get_date()` value, rather than *every single row we have*. Moreover, this way any index on the column would still be valid. The code snippet on the question would be unable to use any index on the `[Due Date]` column. I know this is a `SELECT` clause, but this is worth remembering for the general case.

The full solution for this scenario now looks like this:

```
COALESCE(
    CASE WHEN ai.[Due Date] < CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 120) THEN '[due] ' ELSE '' END
    + FORMAT(CAST(ai.[Due Date]) AS Date), 'MM-dd-yyyy')
, ' ') AS [TD]
```

Again, **only** do this if you can't get your raw column data into a `DateTime` format. That is what you really want here.

#### The column uses the a type from `varchar` family, you can't fix it, and the format is not semantic or not consistent

Oh boy. This is where you really don't want to be. If you can do nothing else, at *least* see if you can start getting consistent and semantic values into your column. At this point, we are stuck with doing extra work on every row we have (possibly more than once) for pretty much every query. Here we go:

```
COALESCE(
    CASE WHEN CAST(ai.[Due Date] AS DATETIME2)  < GETDATE() THEN '[due] ' ELSE '' END 
    + FORMAT(CAST(ai.[Due Date] AS DATETIME2), 'MM-dd-yyyy')
, ' ') AS [TD]
```

The code doesn't look much different than other options, but the performance characteristics will be *extremely* different... potentially multiple orders of magnitude worse.

Remember: because of internationalization and time zone issues, converting between strings and dates is surprisingly slow and expensive. Avoid doing that whenever possible in all your queries.

Comment: thank you for the descriptive response that is well explained. This works out just fine!

Answer (score 6):

The traditional way is to use `convert()`:

```
convert(varchar(10), ai.[Due Date], 110)
```

A more versatile method uses `format()`:

```
select format(ai.[Due Date], 'dd-MM-yyyy')
```